# What is the axle length of this?

Tags: part-identification, technic

[image]What are the lengths of the bottom axles on this picture? Like 5L

[image]

Comment: That's quite a bad picture. I'm not even sure what belongs to the assembly that you're talking about the bottom of, so I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: To find the length of an axle, you can just hold it next to a regular lego brick or plate, and count the studs. If the axle is as long as 5 studs, it's a 5L axle.

Comment: I have updated the picture so it is more clear

Comment: which video are using?

Comment: delayed, I'm sorry for that video

Answer (score 2):

It's running through 2 [33299 Technic Crank](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=33299#T=C) pieces and is as wide as the pins of 2 crank pieces side-by-side.

[image]

That would make it a [4L axle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3705#T=C) which typically are black.

[image]